# Docker COPY . . for bundling

Tags: docker

I am working on creating a docker image with the following

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

I am confused about the following line

```
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
```

What exactly is meant here by bundling? Copy everything? IF that is the case why is it copying the `package.json` file beforehand?

Comment: This is an almost universal Docker pattern which will cause a second `docker build` to not re-run the `npm install` step if the `package.json` hasn't changed.  [How to cache the RUN npm install instruction when docker build a Dockerfile](/questions/35774714/how-to-cache-the-run-npm-install-instruction-when-docker-build-a-dockerfile) has a couple of explanations of the mechanism and pattern.

Comment: Another part of the pattern is you have to add `node_modules/` in your `.dockerignore`

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about the exact same thing.

The solution is the distinction between your application and its dependencies: Running `npm install` after copying `package.json` only installs the dependencies (creating the `node_modules` folder), but your application code is still not inside the container. That's what `COPY . .` does. I don't think the word "bundle" has any special meaning here, since it is just a normal file copy operation.

Separating those steps means the results of `npm install` (i.e. the state of the container after executing the command) can be cached by docker and thus don't have to be executed every time a part of the application code changes. This makes deploys faster.

PS: When talking about making deploys faster, have a look at `npm ci`: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable

Answer (score -1):

To bundle your app's source code inside the Docker image, use the COPY instruction:

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information as to why this would work?